# Maya API - Move CV with Kinect

Tags: c++, maya, kinect-sdk, mel

I’m trying to create a 64-bit plug-in for Autodesk Maya 2013. The aim of this plug-in is to be able to model objects through the Kinect.

In context, with the plug-in you can select the CV of a created object. To specify you want to move the selected points, the position of selected CV is updated constantly.

Here is my problem, when I try to update the position of a selected CV of an object, the result is not displayed on the screen.

I have tried many ways without getting any result, as an example:

1) when I do the setPosition the point doesn’t update.

```
for ( ; !iter.isDone(); iter.next() ) {
    iter.getDagPath( mdagPath, mComponent );
    MItSurfaceCV sCvFn( mdagPath, mComponent, true, &stat );

    if ( MS::kSuccess == stat ) {
        for ( ; !sCvFn.isDone(); sCvFn.nextRow() ) {
            for ( ; !sCvFn.isRowDone(); sCvFn.next() ) {
                MPoint pto(pHand.posX, pHand.posY, pHand.posZ);
                sCvFn.setPosition(pto, MSpace::kWorld);
            }
        }
    }
    sCvFn.updateSurface();
 }
```

2) in this case, if you iterate over the array newCVS before doing the `setCVs` you can see the updated points.
But then, when doing `setCVs` and looking for the position in the CV array of the object (doing a `getCVs`) the position of the modified CV doesn’t change.

```
for ( ; !iter.isDone(); iter.next() ) {
    stat = iter.getDagPath( mdagPath, mComponent );

    if(stat == MS::kSuccess) {
        MFnNurbsSurface surf(mdagPath);
        MItSurfaceCV sCvFn( mdagPath, mComponent, true, &stat );
        MPointArray currentCV;
        surf.getCVs(currentCV, MSpace::kWorld); 
        MPointArray newCVS(currentCV.length(), MPoint::origin);
        newCVS.setLength(currentCV.length());

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < currentCV.length(); i++){
            newCVS[i] = newCVS[i] + currentCV[i];
        }

        int index;

        if ( MS::kSuccess == stat ) {

        for ( ; !sCvFn.isDone(); sCvFn.nextRow() ) {
            for ( ; !sCvFn.isRowDone(); sCvFn.next() ) {
                sCvFn.getIndex(indexU, indexV);
                int posArray = indexU * surf.numCVsInV() + indexV;
                index = posArray;
                MVector diff = MPoint(pHand.posX, pHand.posY, pHand.posZ)                   - currentCV[posArray];
                newCVS[posArray] = newCVS[posArray] + diff;
            }
        }
        surf.setCVs(newCVS, MSpace::kWorld);
        surf.updateSurface();
    }
 }
```

3) When having CV selected in Maya, I tried to move this points with MEL commands. For this, I use the “MGlobal::executeCommand” function, but still nothing happens.

Finally, I changed `executeCommand` to `executeCommandOnIdle`. In this case, the object change correctly but the procedure crashes, perhaps, because this procedure is executed many times per second.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem or knows something about this.

Comment: Is this using the Microsoft SDK?

Comment: I used Maya 2013 for windows and Windows SDK of Kinect